# can one predict variable using scikit-learn rather binary classification if yes than how

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working in the field of Pharmaceutical sciences, I work on 
chemical compounds and with calculating their chemical properties or descriptors we can predict certain biological function of that compounds. I use python and R programming language for the same and also use Weka machine learning tool. Weka provides facility for binary prediction using SVM and other supporting algorithms.

Ex data set: **Training set**

```
Chem_ID   MW LogP HbD HbE IC50 Class_label
  001    232  5    0   2    20    0
  002    280  2    1   4    41    1
  003    240  5    0   2    22    0
  004    300  4    1   5    48    1
  005    245  2    0   2    24    0
  006    255  1    0   2    20    0
  007    299  5    1   4    49    1
```

**Test set**

```
Chem_ID  MW   LogP HbD HbE IC50 Class_label
    000   255  1    0   2    20
```

In weka there are few algorithm with them we can predict the "class_label" or we can also predict specific variable (we usually predict "IC50" values ), does scikit-learn or any other machine learning library in python  having that capabilities. if yes how can we use it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a regression problem. There are many different models to solve a regression problem, from a simple [Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression), to [Support Vector Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR) or [Decision Tree Regressors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor) (and many more).

They work similarly to binary classifier: You give them your training data and instead of 0/1 labels you give them target values to train. In your case you would take the feature you want to predict as target value and delete it form the training data.

Short example:

```
target_values = training_set['IC50']
training_data = training_set.drop('IC50')

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(training_data, target_values)

test_data = test_set.drop('IC50')

predicted_values = clf.predict(test_data)
```

Comment: thanks for the response can we use Naive Bayes or Random forest  or any other algo apart from Linear Regression specifically within scikit-learn  for the same

Comment: @user3218971 [Random Forest Regressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) is one of the available random forest models for regression (others can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble) every model ending with Regressor is suitable for regression). I have no experience with using Naive Bayes for regression and I think it is generally only used for classification.